# The use of globle in regular expression

Tags: php, javascript

I used the regular expression `(/\<+\/+\s+/gm,"</")`. If i remove the g the regular expression don't work. Please let me know technical difference between 'g-global and m-multiple'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

- /g enables "global" matching. When
  using the replace() method, specify
  this modifier to replace all matches,
  rather than only the first one.
- /i makes the regex match case insensitive.
- /m enables "multi-line mode". In this
  mode, the caret and dollar match
  before and after newlines in the
  subject string.

Answer (score 0):

See also http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Also quote the relevant parts of that page.  Link-only answers are under-appreciated because: (1) The reader has to muck through another site, (2) Such linked pages often change or disappear.

Comment: (1) Ok, you are right. (2) in this case I doubt this page would change or disappear.